# create an NSArray of substrings from a NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have a `NSString` that contains numbers and characters. I would like to know the best way to make an `NSArray` of `NSStrings` that contain 2 characters each from the main string.

For instance if the original `NSString` looked like this

```
AFC23S4QL0
```

your NSArray of substrings would look like this

```
ARRAY {
  AF,
  C2,
  3S,
  4Q,
  L0 
}
```

Comment: Best way in what sense? Few code lines? Fast execution? (For short strings or huge strings?) Readability?

Comment: You should really have a look at the `NSString` methods if this causes a problem for you, because this is just a simple loop ...

Comment: Did you have a question?  Can't you just code this?  What is there to ask about here??

Comment: Have you actually tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [substringWithRange:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) for this.

```
NSString *subStr = @"";
int strLen = [yourString length];
BOOL flag = (strLen %2 == 0) ? YES : NO;
for (int index = 0; index < strLen; index+=2)
{
    if((strLen-1 == index) && !flag)
    {
       subStr = [yourString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, 1)];
    }
    else
    {
        subStr = [yourString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, 2)];
    }
    [yourArray addObject:subStr];
}
```

Comment: @RichTolley no it shouldn't.

Comment: @Midhun - your update is incorrect and will crash. You want `index < strLen` in the loop and the `if` would be `index == strLen - 1 && !flag`.

Comment: @rmaddy: I just changed to this `int strLen = [yourString length]-2;`. I think it is ok now, I don't have mac machine with me right now, else I would have checked it

Comment: worked like a charm. thank you very much. I have used NSRange before but just to pull singular values out.. i had no idea how to encorporate it with multiple items.

Comment: That will fail if the original string is 1 character.